# im getting error when performing insert multiple records

Tags: php

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))

$servername = "localhost";
$dbname = "school";


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " .  mysqli_connect_error());
} 


$teacher_id=$_SESSION['id'];
$student_id=$_POST['student_id'];
$subject=$_POST['subject'];
$description=$_POST['description'];


$sql="INSERT INTO t_sent (teacher_id, student_id, subject, description)
VALUES
('$_SESSION[id]', '$_POST[student_id]', '$_POST[subject]', '$_POST[description]')";

$sql .="INSERT INTO p_inbox (teacher_id, student_id, subject, description)
VALUES
('$_SESSION[id]', '$_POST[student_id]', '$_POST[subject]', '$_POST[description]')";


if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

and im getting this error message when im adding records

Error:

```
INSERT INTO t_sent (teacher_id, student_id, subject, description) VALUES ('Badri', 'ca11099', 'cm ', 'cm')INSERT INTO p_inbox (teacher_id, student_id, subject, description) VALUES ('Badri', 'ca11099', 'cm ', 'cm')
No database selected
```

I don't know what I'm missing

Comment: You need to add the database username and password, otherwise it thinks that $dbname is the username and no database name was provided.

Comment: `mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd")` this is how the method should be used. You are missing parameters. Head over to - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you missed out the syntax for mysqli_connet

```
mysqli_connect(host, user,password, db);
```

Please let me know if it didnt work for you.

Comment: Can you please let me know the errors so I can see the matters

Comment: Error: INSERT INTO t_sent (teacher_id, student_id, subject, description) VALUES ('Badri', 'ca11099', 'cm ', 'cm')INSERT INTO p_inbox (teacher_id, student_id, subject, description) VALUES ('Badri', 'ca11099', 'cm ', 'cm')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO p_inbox (teacher_id, student_id, subject, description) VALUES ('Ba' at line 3

Comment: $sql  = "SELECT CURRENT_USER();";
$sql .= "SELECT Name FROM City ORDER BY ID LIMIT 20, 5";               You have missed the semicolon(;) in side the query. Hope now it will work for you.

Comment: thank you very much... its working... u are the best!!

Answer (score 0):

First of all it looks like you are incorrectly using an if statement - namely

`if(isset($_SESSION['id']))`.

That `if` statement will only apply to the very next line (`$servername = "localhost";`). You need to wrap the code you want that statement to apply to with { } (judging by your code, it's every line after that).

Your parameters for mysqli_connect() are wrong - it should be

`mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);`

You are missing the username and password which should go  before the database name.

You're also not sanitizing or escaping your input which is very bad and can lead to [SQL injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).  You should *never* directly take user input and run queries against that.

Comment: so how u suggest me to do the coding.. i am new to this world of php... plz help me.. :D

Comment: There's many different ways, but a simple search will provide you with tons of examples in PHP for performing database operations and avoiding SQL injection attacks.  Check out http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php for a function to use on your existing code

Answer (score 0):

Use correct mysqli_connect() with all the parameters:

```
 <?php
    $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username,$password, $database_name);

    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }
    ?>
```

Also, You can select database using mysqli_select_db() function